# Create a custom office document property that is linked to content inside the document

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to create a custom document property in powerpoint that is linked to the document content in C#.

I found various examples, but they all create custom document properties WITHOUT linking to document content.

What I want to achieve is that a user selects text in any shape and by clicking a button, the custom document property is created together with a link to the source. 
I want to be able to retrieve it later and on demand jump to the linked content.

Here is the code snippet that I'm using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
properties = (Office.DocumentProperties)this.myOCMModule.PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.CustomDocumentProperties;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Selection powerPointSelection  = this.myMainOCMModule.PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection;
PowerPoint.TextRange textRange = powerPointSelection.TextRange;
properties.Add("Test1", true, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, textRange.Text, textRange);
```

The custom property is created but the link is not valid. When I open the custom properties in PowerPoint, it the custom property appears with a broken link.

When iIdo it manually by creating a custom property it works when doing it like described [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/bookmarks-powerpoint-t2739130.html). I want to do the same thing programmatically.

In the MS reference it states

> The source of the specified link is defined by the container application.

Maybe it can't resolve the textRange variable properly?

Does anyone know how i can make this work?

Comment: The link is a rather old one; PPT has changed so much since that I can't even find the Edit/GoTo option, and when you add a property that links to content in PPT 2010, it does show a link icon next to it, but I can't see any way of getting it to DO anything.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above, but I think there may be a more reliable/controllable way of doing what you want.

When the user creates one of your "bookmarks", your code can add a tag to the shape in question.  In VBA, this is as simple as:

```
oSh.Tags.Add "TagName", "Value of my tag"
' assuming oSh contains a reference to the shape you want to mark
```

You'd use the same tag name each time but change the tag value for each shape.

To jump to the tagged content, something like this (insert obligatory aircode warning here):

```
Sub JumpToTaggedContent(sTagValue as String)
Dim oSl as Slide
Dim oSh as Shape
  For Each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh in oSl.Shapes
       If oSh.Tags("TagName") = sTagValue Then  ' you've found it
          ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide(oSh.Parent.SlideIndex)
          oSh.Select
          Exit Sub
       End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```